# Javascript - Why this exception occured?

Tags: javascript

In the login function below, after it is run the success alert (authenticated with success), it catches an error too, both the success and the error messages are shown. Why?

Any suggestions? Please help. Thanks!

the login function:

```
 $scope.login = function() {        
     $signin_email = $scope.member.email; 
     $signin_password = $scope.member.password;

     // sign in
      Auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword($signin_email, $signin_password)
        .then(function(firebaseUser) {
          authenticated = true;
          alert(firebaseUser.email + " logou caralho!");
           $state.go('tabsController.home');
            check();
        }).catch(function(error) {
            authenticated = false;
            alert(error.message);
          //$scope.error = error;
          check();
        });
    };
```

Comment: what is the error in console?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Promises "fall through" to further steps if they're not explicitly rejected. Add a call to `Promise.reject` inside your `catch` method:

```
Auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword($signin_email, $signin_password)
  .then(function(firebaseUser) {
    authenticated = true;
    alert(firebaseUser.email + " logou caralho!");
    $state.go('tabsController.home');
    check();
  }).catch(function(error) 
    authenticated = false;
    alert(error.message);
    //$scope.error = error;
    check();
    return Promise.reject();
  });
```

Comment: huh? order of catch/then is not relevant. They are both properties of same object

Comment: so what is point of extra Promise.reject() ? This isn't making sense

Comment: @Mr.Malaka Feel free to accept if it helped; I'm not sure what problem charlieftl has with it.

Comment: @furkle i still in doubt why the exception occured , but your way works to me

Comment: `Promise.reject()` creates a new rejected promise, but you're not doing anything with it, so it's just dead code. You'd need to return this promise from the `.catch` handler for it to have any effect. And besides, the error shouldn't fall through in the first place since it is not passed to the caller.

Comment: @charlietfl `.catch` is called on the *new* promise returned by `.then`, which is not the same as the original promise (it will resolve to the value returned by the handler of `.then`), so the order does actually make a difference.

Comment: @Frxstrem Thanks, added the `return` part, unsure why it was working, then. Not entirely sure what you mean by "since it is not passed to the caller."